# Moving vector in an object for twice

Tags: c++, move-semantics

Is the following the correct way to move a vector for twice?

The program implements a Layer, whose next layer is a `Null_layer` by default.

Rebind would return a new Layer object with binding to a new `Next_layer`.

Somehow Clion says the `std::move(vec_)` in the `rebind` method has an error: "Parameter type mismatch: Expression must be rvalue"

But the program can compile and "seems" to run fine.

Use Case:
rebind is for binding an existing layer as the next layer of this layer. This is for building a pile of layers from bottom to top. When the next layer is added to the pile, the next layer exists and I use rebind for this layer

Thanks.

Test:

```
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct Null_layer { int x; };

template<typename T, typename Next_layer=Null_layer>
class Layer {
public:
    explicit Layer(std::vector<T>&& v,
                   Next_layer nx = Next_layer())
            : vec_(std::move(v)), nx_(nx) {}

    // Create new object whose next layer is an existing 
    // layer nx. But the new object would steal other
    // data (e.g. vec_) of this object.
    template<typename Nx2>
    auto rebind(Nx2& nx) {
        return Layer<T, Nx2&>(std::move(vec_), nx);
    };

    Next_layer nx_;
    std::vector<T> vec_;
};

int main() {
    Layer<int, Null_layer> a(std::vector<int>(10));
    Null_layer n;
    a.vec_[0] = 100;
    auto b = a.rebind(n);
    std::cout << b.vec_[0] << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Two things: `vec_(std::move(v))` seems wrong, you should `std::forward` instead; type of `Layer<T, Nx2&>` looks off, perhaps you wanted `Layer<T, Nx2>` (no ampersand after Nx2)

Comment: @hauron why would he need to `std::forward`? there is no type deduction here, thus there will be no forwarding/universal reference. `std::move` is good here

Comment: @Fureeish afaik to `T&&` will bind either an rvalue or lvalue ref, can't be sure at this place which one. With `std::move` he will always cast the parameter to an rvalue, and move from it - this could be bad, if the caller wishes to reuse passed in lvalue. (in this particular example he's passing in a temporary, so it's fine)

Comment: yes, `T&&`. Exactly `T&&`. Not `std::vector<T>&&`. The last one is simply an rvalue reference. For universal references, the type MUST be `T&&`. This constructor will always be called with an rvalue

Comment: @Fureeish you're right, doesn't it also mean that `std::move` is redudant - the type is already an rvalue ref, no need for cast? (for the curious reader a link to Scott Meyer's short article about this: https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers)

Comment: No, the `std::move` is **not** redundant. While `v` is an rvalue ref, when it is being passed to initializer list, it will be treated as lvalue ref, since it has a name. The `std::move` is necessary and correctly used here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171033/discussion-between-fureeish-and-hauron).

Comment: Going back to the original question: this code compiles fine for me on GCC 7.3. It just gives a warning about the order of initialisation. I do however agree on the `Layer<T, Nx2&>`. Don't you simply need `Layer<T, Nx2>`?

Comment: I want a doubly "linked" list of layers within an onion of layers. The onion stores the linkage in one direction, the code shown would deal with the linkage in the opposite direction.